# In CakePHP 3.0 what is the difference between initialize() and beforeFilter()?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm transitioning from CakePHP 2.x and it's not clear to me what the difference is between `initialize()` and `beforeFilter()`. There seems to be a lot of overlap between them. When should I use one and not the other?

Answer (score 7):

It is the order in which the events happen. `initialize()` is called right after the `__construct()` method, whereas `beforeFilter()` is only called if an action is dispatched.

Comment: Thanks can you elaborate on what you mean by "only called if an action is dispatched"?

Comment: before a controller action is called, for example `index()`, `add()`, `delete()` ...

Comment: As opposed to when a controller is just instantiated manually? Is that the idea?

Answer (score 4):

`initialize()` is always called.

`beforeFilter()` is optional. If it is present, it is:

> called before the controller’s beforeFilter method, but after the controller’s initialize() method.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#component-callbacks

Comment: That's specific to when those methods are used in components.

Comment: the comment you get from cookbook is not for controllers its for component